# Permissions issues with ADCCSharp.dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, active-directory, permissions

I have used the `ADCCSharp.dll` file to check if a user exists in Active Directory. I use this in the login form of a Windows application. The problem is that some users can not access the program and they are (exist) in Active Directory.
 I guess there must be some right, permissions, or security problem.

How can I set rights to the DLL I use? 
There should be something in square brackets called right above the methods that uses code from that DLL.

Comment: Use the DirectoryServices to query Active Directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941002/how-can-i-get-domain-user-from-an-ad-directoryentry

Comment: What is ADCCSharp.dll and where did you get it from?