# Determine the domain of a user in an Active Directory search result

Tags: c#, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get DOMAIN\USER from an AD DirectoryEntry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941002/how-can-i-get-domain-user-from-an-ad-directoryentry)

Here is what I have right now:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
SearchResult result;
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", groupName);
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
result = search.FindOne();
```

Note that `groupName` (which a parameter passed into the method representing the name of the group to search in) can be a universal group, which means it might contain accounts from other domains.

Which property in the `searchresultcollection` should I use to find the domain the account originates from, or even better is there a webpage that has a list of all the properties available to this particular collection?

Comment: Which collection are you referring to? i don't see any reference to a `searchpropertycollection` in your code.

Comment: It's called searchresultcollection. My apologies. Also @joshperry, that question didn't come up in the list of suggestions. The content of the question is not quite duplicate, but one of the answers does answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: However, a list of properties would still be good :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distinguishedName` property of any AD object should always contain the full LDAP compatible path to that object, e.g.

```
CN=John Doe,OU=Marketing,OU=IntlSales,DC=YourMegaCorp,DC=com
```

Based on that DN you can figure out the domain (`DC=YourMegaCorp,DC=com`) that this user came from. I don't think there's any other (default) AD attribute that would give you just the domain, though - you'll need to "crack and parse" that DN to get the info you need.